# Java Cucumber says 0 scenarios

Tags: java, junit, webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to run some test for cucumber (to learn)
I have the below:

myapplication.feature with

```
Feature: test                                                                      
   Scenario: login
   Given open firefox and start app 
   When enter details    
   Then login happens
```

the class runner:

```
package runnerPackage;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="C:/Users/lucian.patrascu/workspace/tst/features/myapplication.feature",
glue={"stepdefinition"},dryRun = false)
public class Runner {
}
```

step definition:

```
public class test1 {

    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    @Given("^open firefox and start app$")
    public void open_firefox_and_start_app(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.out.println("worked");
    }

    @When("^enter details$")
    public void enter_details(){
        driver.navigate().to("hi5.com");
    }
    @Then("^login happens$")
    public void login(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signInBtn'][@tabindex='3']"));
    }
}
```

I had TestNG and Junit libraries first, then i removed TestNg and same result.
I tried with various path for  @CucumberOptions(features=... ) and still it says:

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

Could you advise, as I cannot find a way to fix it

Comment: Have you tried the relative path "tst/features" or "features"?

Comment: Could you please post your `myapplication.feature` file.

Comment: Feature: test
 Scenario: login                                                                                   
 Given open firefox and start app                                                                When enter details                                                                               Then login happens
 
 it;s in the first lines written, i cannot format right sorry (it;s in the initial comment)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start with this simple project and then check where are the differences in yours. It could be a typo in the path, or something else we cannot know based on your provided input.

assume following structure

```
/tmp/cuke/tst/features/myapplication.feature
/tmp/cuke/src/test/java/runnerPackage/Runner.java
/tmp/cuke/pom.xml
```

**myapplication.feature**

```
Feature: test
    Scenario: login
        Given open firefox
        And start app
        When enter details
        Then login happens
```

**Runner.java**

```
package runnerPackage;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features="/tmp/cuke/tst/features/myapplication.feature",
    glue={"stepdefinition"},
    dryRun = false
)
public class Runner {
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suboptimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cuke</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

run the Cucumber runner `Runner`

```
cd /tmp/cuke
mvn test -Dtest=Runner
```

results in

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runnerPackage.Runner

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.021s
...
```

**edit** Based on the provided Eclipse project. The tests are supposed to be executed by TestNG. Therefor Cucumber runner must extend [cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/testng/src/main/java/cucumber/api/testng/AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java)

assume following structure

```
/tmp/cuke/src/test/java/runnerPackage/RunnerTest.java
/tmp/cuke/features/myapplication.feature
/tmp/cuke/pom.xml
```

**myapplication.feature**

```
Feature: test
    Scenario: login
        Given open firefox
        And start app
        When enter details
        Then login happens
```

**RunnerTest.java**

```
package runnerPackage;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = "features")
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.suboptimal</groupId>
    <artifactId>cuke</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <surefire.version>2.18.1</surefire.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

run the test

```
cd /tmp/cuke
mvn test
```

results in

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running runnerPackage.RunnerTest
Configuring TestNG with:
org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@6bf2d08e

1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.018s
...
```

Comment: thanls for the answer, the thing is i'm not using mavem, to follow your example..i'll give it againa good look, i fallowed an online tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv7hHrVX_Zg) ...and did almost everything the same

Comment: in my feature files for "GIVE" i have no error for "When"&"Then"  >>> step 'enter details' does not have a matching glue

Comment: in the failure trace it says: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: C:\workspace\tst\features\myapplication.feature
 at cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.<init>(FileResourceIterator.java:54)

Even if i change the feature to the right path it still gives same error message, for the same erroneous path

Comment: regardless of what i specify within the feature property it always gives error:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory:C:\workspace\tst\features\myapplication.feature

Comment: i've downloaded latest jars, now it says:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.formatter(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lcucumber/api/formatter/Formatter;

Comment: Can you store the whole source somewhere (GitHub, Bitbucket, etc.) if it's to big to post in your original question. Seems you are missing some dependencies now. Have you checked with `dir C:\workspace\tst\features\myapplication.feature` if the file exist.

Comment: the correct path is : C:\Users\lucian.patrascu\workspace\tst\features, that it finds.   The one it searches for is not correct, i don't know how to change where it is searching  as it goes to the same folder regardless of what i input

Comment: https://github.com/patrascujustinlucian/selenium  for the projects folder

Comment: @MihaiMihaescu I added a TestNG example. Please have a look.

Comment: this might sound lame, but where is it added? i cannot find it

Comment: @MihaiMihaescu In my above answer starting with `Based on the provided Eclipse project. ...` ;-)

Comment: If I recall correctly I had a similar problem and fixed it by marking the correct directories as 'test root', 'test resources root', etc. Not sure if those are Maven specific thoughl.

Comment: @Marit What you describe sounds more like an IDE (IntelliJ ?) feature. If a project is set up as a Maven project it should work as expected without additional tweaks in the IDE.

Comment: @SubOptimal Yes, it was in IntelliJ. This happened when I started the project as a Java project instead of a Maven project, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove the option **dryRun = false**

Thanks

Comment: It can be really helpful if you can elaborate on why you think that this would work.